# Best Resources for Solana beginners

Tags: anchor, rust, developer, beginner, resources

Which are the best Resources to start developing on Solana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When learning a new language or framework I always prefer to follow a simple tutorial that walks me through building a basic app. This gives me a general idea of the language and the workflow.

After I have the basics down I try expand on the concepts and patterns I've just implemented by try build out my own idea using docs and StackOverflow as reference.

If you prefer this learning approach I'd HIGHLY recommend starting with [Loris Leiva's Create A Solana DApp From Scratch](https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch) tutorial. It's just detailed enough to give you a good foundation but not so much that you get bogged down and overwhelmed.

Another option for starter tutorials is [BuilderSpace](https://buildspace.so/) - There's some pretty good ones on their, albeit a bit more basic but definitely worth doing.

As always, for reference and guides when expanding the concepts of the tutorials it's always good to look at the [official documentation](https://solana.com/developers).

And finally, another **extremely** useful site is [Soldev.app](https://soldev.app/library/tutorials). They've aggregated a list of some of the most useful tutorials for getting started.

All this assumes you've programmed before and have at least played around a bit with Rust (It can have a steepish learning curve so highly recommend you look at some of the basics of the language before jumping in to Solana)

Have fun and good luck :)

*UPDATE:*

Another entry level tutorial that's definitely worth trying is [Figment.io's Solana 101](https://learn.figment.io/protocols/solana) course.

In addition to the course, Figment has also aggregated some tutorials [here](https://learn.figment.io/tutorials).
(They have tutorials for different block chains so filter by Solana).

Answer (score 0):

Buildspace was an excellent resource early on, and has come a long way as a product over the last year.

[buildspace.so/learn-solana](https://buildspace.so/learn-solana)

Answer (score 0):

Solana maintain a list of resources here: https://solana.com/developers

Comment: To be fair the same applies to whatever links they post directly from the developers site. Best resources questions are not great / lead to ambiguous responses mostly

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to get started with Anchor, and for getting started in Anchor, check out [the anchor book](https://book.anchor-lang.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an entire list from Beginner to Advance!

https://solana-philippines.github.io/#/resources